# When to make a minor-mode

Tags: minor-mode

Have got some elisp functions.  When is it proper to include them in a minor-mode rather than using just a simple elisp file.

What functionality do minor modes provide that cannot be achieved with simply loading a file?

Comment: The question is too broad, and encourages opinion-based answers. Can you ask something more specific about the use or behavior of minor modes? E.g., is there something specific about them that you don't understand or want to know more about?

Comment: I am starting to think that ending up with many minor-modes could be counter-productive.  What features can minor-modes provide that makes one want to use them, rather than using a simple elisp file?  Got some functionality that one would want to have enabled for all major modes, perhaps these general things do not specifically require a minor-mode declaration.

Comment: Have you read the "Major and Minor Modes" chapter in the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modes.html)?

Comment: I know what they are.  My conclusion has been that minor modes are easy to turn "on" or "off".  But besides that I can have the same functionality from just an `el` file.

Comment: I don't really understand your point: minor modes are just `el` files after all. It's just that they are not a catch-all of random functions (however useful those might be): there is an underlying unity in what they provide. If you cannot describe what the functions in your `el` file collectively help to do in a single sentence, then don't bother making them into a minor mode. But that's hopelessly vague, e.g. "They help me be more productive" is a single sentence, but that's not  helpful :-). In any case, I agree with @Drew: the question is too broad for this site.

Comment: This is like asking what to use a *variable* for. If you know what a variable *is* then you can decide how you might want to use a variable in some particular context. A question about using a variable in a particular (well-specified)context could make sense. A question that just asks when to use a variable is too general (for this Q&A site, at least). Similarly, if you know what a *minor mode* **is** then you know how/when to use it, in general. But asking how/whether to use one in some particular, *well-specified* context could be a useful question.

Comment: *"I can have the same functionality from just an el file."* Maybe so (depends on the file and the minor mode). And you might be able to get the same functionality from just a variable (depending...). There are multiple ways to realize a given goal. If you're not specific about the goal/context, then a "when to use" question is typically too broad, and it isn't helpful to others. (It's likely not very useful to you either, as the answers will similarly be vague/broad.)

Comment: Here's some help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you Nick, will use just an `el` file without defining a minor mode.  Then will see whether to define a minor mode in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor mode provides a switch. Often adds or removes hooks. Provides an own keymap. Think at abbrev-mode or whitespace-mode. It's a kind of grouping. For a certain feature, which is useful, but not all the time, so switch it off or on.

Comment: Very clear and helpful explanation,